# Building C3.js graph using json data

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

I'm trying to build c3.js line chart from data grabbed using php from mysql database.

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#linear-chart',
  data: {
    json:lineChartData,
    keys:{
      value: ['date', 'temp'],
    }
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

lineChartData - json data from mysql and looks like:

```
[{date: Wed Mar 13 2019, temp: 200},{.......}]
```

How should be ready json data sent to c3.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily echo your json data into C3.js by doing:

```
var dataset = <?php echo $lineChartData; ?>; 
data: { 
    json: dataset
    }
```

I am using the same pipeline you are using for my web project (mySQL-PHP-C3.js). It is important that your json data is exactly in the format that C3 needs for imput. As you can read in the C3.js documentation (https://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html), data format for time series should be as follows:

```
data: {
       x: 'x',
       //  xFormat: '%Y%m%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
       columns: [
           ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
       //  ['x', '20130101', '20130102', '20130103', '20130104', '20130105', '20130106'],
           ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
           ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
         ]
      },
axis: {
       x: {
           type: 'timeseries',
           tick: {
             format: '%Y-%m-%d'
           }
         }
       }
```

For my data (not time series data), json object looks as follows:

```
{"data1": [0.23, 0.29, 0.19, 0.14, 0.7], "data2": [0, 0.25, 0.61, 0.4, 0.52]}
```

If you follow this structure and add your time data (date) as third dimension to it, you should be able to achive what you want.